# Is there an elevation at any point in an array of digits

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

So.. I'm working on something for which I need to know if a set of ordered digits has any "elevation" to it or, in other words, isn't that set in a completely descending order.

If I have `[3,2,1]`, it should return false, while with any other order of those digits, it should return true. Eg. `[2,3,1]`, becase from left-to-right, there's an elevation between 2 and 3.

I use the following small function:

```
function hasElevation(digits) {
    return digits.slice().sort().reverse().toString() !== digits.toString();
}
```

My question is, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Vanilla JS please!

**UPDATED**: use cases added

```
hasElevation([3,5,4]); // true
hasElevation([3,4,4]); // true
hasElevation([1]); // false
hasElevation([1,1]); // false
hasElevation([5,4,3]); // false
```

Comment: Loop through the array. If the current element is higher than the previous element, return true. If you get to the end without returning, return false.

Comment: That was my original code, however, I thought that would actually be less efficient. I don't know...

Comment: I don't think there can be any more efficient method. Anything that has to go through the entire array will be less efficient than this. Your code goes through the array 4 times, including a sort that's O(n log n).

Comment: You're right. What I wanted to do was a more math-like solution. I just wanted to put it out there, because maybe someone has an elegant, even better solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for every element and the previous element.

```js
function hasElevation(digits) {
    return digits.some(function (a, i, aa) {
        return aa[i - 1] < a;
    });
}

console.log(hasElevation([3, 5, 4])); // true
console.log(hasElevation([3, 4, 4])); // true
console.log(hasElevation([1]));       // false
console.log(hasElevation([1, 1]));    // false
console.log(hasElevation([5, 4, 3])); // false
```

ES6

```js
var hasElevation = digits => digits.some((a, i, aa) => aa[i - 1] < a);

console.log(hasElevation([3, 5, 4])); // true
console.log(hasElevation([3, 4, 4])); // true
console.log(hasElevation([1]));       // false
console.log(hasElevation([1, 1]));    // false
console.log(hasElevation([5, 4, 3])); // false
```

Comment: "If I have `[3,2,1]`, it should return false" but your code returns `true`. Furthermore, I'd use `>=` (respectively `<=`) as I expect `[3, 2, 2]` to return `false` as well.

Comment: should in order return false?

Comment: So! I like this a lot. Same logic, but better application of cycling through the array. Will accept it, but wanna wait a bit longer to see if a math-like solution appears.. : )
Thanks!

Comment: @ppseprus What do you mean by "math-like solution"? Personally, I think Nina's fixed version is fine. It's concise, readable, and worst case is O(n).

Comment: I don't think Nina has to change the current code. It works fine, I've tested it. By a math-like solution I mean something where you use a logic different from the current one. Here we specificly iterate through the array and look for it. Is there another way? For example my original post contains a simple comparison. I rearrange the digits into a new array, in a descending order. If that does not equal qith the original array (sam set, same length), something is swapped. If on is completely descending and the other does not equal to it, that has an elevation. Its another logic...

Comment: @ppseprus, ok, please add some use cases and the wanted result.

Comment: @ppseprus I would call that ["creative"](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22333/creative-ways-to-determine-if-an-array-is-sorted) rather than "math-like"... ;)

Comment: @Nina, added them!

Comment: @beatngu13, that is actually a math solution! :D

Comment: @ppseprus, so it's all fine.

Comment: @Nina, jup! : ) Like I said. Your solution is more efficient than mine and that's what concers me the most, however, I give it a bit more time... :P

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I could not find any other solution.. : )

Answer (score 1):

This would be my solution if `[2,2]` should return true

```js
function isDescending(arr){
  return !arr.reduce((b,e,i) => b && Math.sign(arr[i]-(arr[i+1]||-Infinity)) === 1 ,true);
}

console.log(isDescending([4,3,2,1]));
console.log(isDescending([1,2,3,4]));
console.log(isDescending([4,3,2,2,1]));
```

This would be my solution if `[2,2]` should return false

```js
function isDescending(arr){
  return !arr.reduce((b,e,i) => { var sign = Math.sign(arr[i]-(arr[i+1]||-Infinity));
                                  return b && (sign === 0 || sign === 1);
                                },true);
}

console.log(isDescending([4,3,2,1]));
console.log(isDescending([1,2,3,4]));
console.log(isDescending([4,3,2,2,1]));
```

Comment: So.. `[1,2,3,4]` has no elevation?

Comment: The question isn't about if the digits are descending, but about whether at any point ascending...

Comment: @ppseprus That's exactly what i had thought originally and in fact i had presented my solution accordingly but then i have read this in the question "or, in other words, isn't that set in a completely descending order." which made me to change the code.

Comment: But `[1,2,3,4]` is still not in a "completely descending", because at least at some parts (actually everywhere) it is ascending

Comment: But I very much like the idea of using signs!

Comment: Also.. you should handle `[1,1]`.. It is not descending, but it does not elevate.

Comment: @ppseprus I guess just negating the reduce's result should be sufficient.. but then as per [2,2] case would you like to handle it as a non elevation..? because then the series wouldn't be continuously decreasing as well.

Comment: Completely is not continously. `[2,2]`should be false. There is no elevation in it.

Comment: @ppseprus ok my misunderstanding... the second snippet should be fine i hope.

Comment: Hey! So, tanks for your solution! Approaching from a sings perspective is fresh! I like it! However, I choose the other solution, because the `.some()` will not iterate through the whole array. It has the potential to stop earlier. But thanks! : )